# How do I assign an array to a set of GtkWidget * in C?

Tags: c, gtk

I have an array of label names FlagEnt[NFLAGS] and I want to assign a GtkWidget * to an array flentry[NFLAGS].  I've tried to do it like this:

```
  for (i = 0; i < NFLAGS; i++)
    flentry[i] = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, FlagEnt[i]));
```

That didn't work and I ended up with:

```
(gdb) p flentry
$1 = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}
```

not the array of pointers I was expecting, so I looked at what flentry should look like:

```
(gdb) p &flentry
$3 = (GtkWidget *(*)[8]) 0x5555557cdb60 <flentry>
```

I noticed the extra * in the definition; that must be from the fact that I declared flentry as:

```
static GtkWidget *   flentry[NFLAGS];
```

ie as an array.  I tested this hypothesis with:

```
static GtkWidget * tflentry
tflentry = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, FlagEnt[0]));
```

```
(gdb) p tflentry
$1 = 0x555555aa1d60
(gdb) p *tflentry
$2 = {parent_instance = {g_type_instance = {g_class = 0x5555558e9110}, ref_count = 1, qdata = 0x555555aabdf0}, priv = 0x555555aa1c70}
```

And, Hey presto! tflentry comes up as a valid pointer.  Array problems it is, then.
Then I tried to directly assign an element of the array to a pointer I knew worked:

```
static GtkWidget * tflentry
tflentry = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, FlagEnt[0]));
flentry[0] = tflentry;

(gdb) p tflentry
$2 = 0x555555ab2a00

(gdb) p flentry[0]
$8 = 0x0
```

I don't know how to assign the pointer tflentry to the array flentry[].

Anyone able to give me a clue? :)

Comment: The extra `*` is because you did `p &flentry` instead of `p flentry`. Your first code snippet is correct. As for why you say that it did not work... well you'll need to expand on that, because it's unclear what you mean.

Comment: I've added more detail to the question to clarify some points.